# IE10 downloads PDF file with IFRAME

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-10, pdfobject

I am using Internet Explorer 10 (64 bit).

I am using Adobe pdf plugin to disply embeded PDFs (using iFrame). However this is not displaying the document in the plugin, it displays popup prompt to Save or Cancel.

I am also using PDFObject.js and changed a bit so it works with IE10

```
isIE10 = function(){
    return (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/6") > -1);
};

if(isIE10()){
  targetNode.innerHTML = '<iframe    src="' +url +'" width="' +width +'" height="' +height +'"></iframe>';
  return targetNode.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
} else {
  targetNode.innerHTML = '<object    data="' +url +'" type="application/pdf" width="' +width +'" height="' +height +'"></object>';
  return targetNode.getElementsByTagName("object")[0];
}
```

Comment: It display popup to save because the server didn't return the proper header for the request. This has nothing to do with javascript

Comment: hmm but it does return the proper header. I changed the code so iframe has type="application/pdf" and the response header also has type="application/pdf"

Comment: What happens when you enter the url in the browser address bar instead of loading through an iframe?

Comment: It tries to download the file in both IE 8 and 10. However in IE8 the file is displayed in the pdf plugin correctly..

Comment: You didn't answer my previous question. It could be anything. PDF plugin outdated, headers incorrect, IE config? It's good if you can also show the server side code where you put all of your headers.

Comment: Ah, I made it working now, thought I had the correct header.. looks like it was because of 
response.addHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=document."+metadata.fileExtension.getValue());